# How do I avoid hardcoded strings in activity while inputting for recycler view?

Tags: java, android, string, android-recyclerview

I'm working with `recycler view` and while inserting `String` type text in recycler view I'm using all the hard coded strings and I think it might show problem while translating it into other languages.

I tried to remove string. For example, I removed **"about us"** and kept `R.string.about_us`.  However, it showed error.

```
 wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, R.string.about_us));
 wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "Our Facebook Page"));
 wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "About Us"));
```

Comment: Yes hardcoded string will be not be converted to other language. You have to put `strings.xml` in different `values` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked!

```
wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, getString(R.string.about_us)));
wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, getString(R.string.meme_bazar)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't direct access string from `string.xml` for you need `getResource()`. here is example

```
getResources().getString(R.string.about_us);
```

Your code should be look like

```
wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.about_us)));
wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "Our Facebook Page"));
wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "About Us"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not said the error you got but you need to get the string by calling `getString`, do it like this:

```
wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, context.getString(R.string.about_us)));

wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "Our Facebook Page"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the values dialog box more often, in your case the one for `String` fields. There you can use "New resource" where you enter it's id and value at the same time. Then you install the ui that helps you do the translations.

Answer (score 0):

For Activity Use,

```
wordList.add(new Word(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background), getResource().getString(R.string.about_us)));
```

For Fragment Or Adapter Use,

```
wordList.add(new Word(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background), context.getResource().getString(R.string.about_us)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code like below :

```
    wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, 
    getActivity().getString(R.string.about_us));

    wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, 
    getActivity().getString(R.string.our_facebook_page));   
    //our_facebook_page = "Our Facebook Page"

    wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, 
    getActivity().getString(R.string.about_us));   
    //about_us ="About Us"
```

You should also put a check like :

```
getActivity() != null
```

before executing above code to prevent the famous **NullPointerException.**